# symfony exception not returning the right status code

Tags: php, symfony

It should be responding with a `403` status code, but for the following code I get this response:

`Full authentication is required to access this resource. (500 Internal Server Error)`

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    private function _accessControl()
    {
        if (false === $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException();
        }
    }
```

Here's the [API reference for the AccessDeniedException class](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Exception/AccessDeniedException.html)

and the code:

```
/**
 * AccessDeniedException is thrown when the account has not the required role.
 *
 * @author Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
*/
class AccessDeniedException extends \RuntimeException
{
    public function __construct($message = 'Access Denied', \Exception $previous = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($message, 403, $previous);
    }
}
```

Using `throw new HttpException(403);` in the same place in my code returns the right status code

Comment: Are you testing it in the dev environment or production environment?

Comment: It should throw with the message "Access Denied" and yours doesnt. It's another exception that is being thrown.

Comment: dev environment and I just added a line to my question

Comment: Using throw new HttpException(403); in the same place in my code returns the right status code

Comment: Please also post that part of your code that verifies which namespace ```throw new AccessDeniedException();``` refers to. Also try using step-by-step debug (or temporarily adding a line ```echo 'hello'; die;``` to the quoted constructor) to ensure that the quoted exception class is thrown!

Comment: And search your code for 'kernel.exception' listeners they might sneak in another exception instead of the one originally thrown out of a controller.